# golang, parsing xml site

Tags: go, xml-parsing

When I try to parse the xml site, nothing works for me and output "[]" . As a result, I decided to download the xml file of this site, and after I remove
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>`, then everything works out for me. Is it possible to somehow read the data without deleting this fragment?

```
type ValCurs struct {
XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ValCurs"`
Date    string   `xml:"Date, attr"`
Name    string   `xml:"name, attr"`
Valute  []Valute `xml:"Valute"`
}

type Valute struct {
XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"Valute"`
CharCode string   `xml:"CharCode"`
Nominal  string   `xml:"Nominal"`
Name     string   `xml:"Name"`
Value    string   `xml:"Value"`
}

func main() {

resp, _ := http.Get("http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp")
defer resp.Body.Close()
req, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
var val ValCurs

xml.Unmarshal(req, &val)
fmt.Println(val)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, maybe I figured it out, but I'm not sure if I did everything right.
I installed charmap package "github.com/aglyzov/charmap"
And cut off the byts

```
res1 := bytes.Trim(byts, "<? ?>")
```

After that everything works as I would like